# Caps Lock indicator

Tags: statusline

I would like if there is any way to have some sort of a indicator on screen for when Caps Lock is on.

The status line seems like the right place but I am looking for any method whether for `vim` or `neovim` with a plugin or not

Comment: From Vim's point of view, CAPSLOCK doesn't exist so it can't notify you when the key is pressed. That said, you almost certainly have a led for that somewhere on your keyboard.

Comment: Do you have a solution to your problem? If the solution is published maybe you could accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I was waiting for another better answer as the extension seems abandonned and does not work for me.

Comment: I understand in particular the refresh is not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can add such an indicator to your status line using the [vimcaps](https://github.com/suxpert/vimcaps) plugin.

Comment: Alas it does not work on my machine ( I am on Fedora). The C part of the plugin fails to compile into a .so. I tried to install the needed packages for X11 dependencies and managed to compile a simple program with the same headers and the right flag but the plugin still fails. I inspected the makefile but couldn't find where the error was yet.